# NFC Loop Antenna placement

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, rfid, nfc

I'm trying to design a NFC loop antenna according to the following specification:

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa135a/sloa135a.pdf

In the design the loops are placed on the top layer of the PCB, same as rest of the circuitry. However, when mounted with the back of the PCBS against a flat surface and the RFID tag on the other side of the flat surface, the antenna loops are father away from the tag than they could be. 
My questions are:

1. Is there a downside to moving the antenna loops to opposite side of the PCB? That it, bottom layer.
2. Are typical NFC-antennas equally effective with the RFID tag placed under or over them? I believe they must be due to the fact that field lines should be symmetrical on the back and front.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally in this case i would say there will be no significant downside, since the pcb-thickness is only usually around 1-1.6mm. This does not influence the reader.
In most cases there is space of air and an enclosure between the tag and reader, which is a much greater distance than just the pcb

Yes, the tags are equally effective.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would prefer that someone else also confirms the information before I accept the answer. 
If you have other related considerations or information that might be useful you are most welcome to share it in the comments. :)